# paramiko exec_command(shell_script) prompt not getting answered via stdin.write()

Tags: python, shell, ssh, prompt, paramiko

I'm trying to install a software(it's basically a shell script) on remote Linux machine using paramiko.
I know that the software once run will prompt for a end user license acceptance (y or n). 
So I wrote the script as below,

====================
`

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect ('remoteLinuxHost', username=r'user', password='pass')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(r'/full/path/to/software')

stdin.write("y\n")
stdin.flush()

print "output ", stdout.readlines()
```

## `

This works absolutely fine on Red hat machine, but the same code hangs forever on Suse Linux! (Just prints output and script will just keeps running)

NOTE: 
1.When it hangs on Suse, I manually checked

```
ps -ef | grep 'software' that displayed,
root     10941 10938  1 21:10 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh software
root     11050 11031  0 21:10 ?        00:00:00 more softwareEndUserLicense.txt
```

This confirmed that prompt (y or n) is not being answered here.

2. I've tried using ssh.invoke_shell() method with the same result, also have cross checked permission of the software, gave sudo, preceded it with /bin/bash nothing working.

Please suggest. 
Thank you.